# R find composition for machine learning

Tags: r, machine-learning

I would like to find the best variables out of all variables,
For instance I have 9 variables,

```
vector=c("blood pressure", "sugar level", "bmi", "weight","skin thickness","weight", "gender")
```

I would like to take composition of all five variables, to calculate the best RMSE, than check for all 6 and then 7, 8 and 9, I would like to create a vector for all five possible, all six, all seven, all eight, what would be the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `vector` example you gave only has 7 elements, not 9 ... but this incantation will give you all combinations of 5, 6, 7 elements:

```r
r <- lapply(5:7, combn, x = vector, simplify = FALSE) |> 
   unlist(recursive=FALSE)
length(r) ## 29 = choose(7,5) + choose(7,6) + choose(7,7)
```

```r
head(r,2)
[[1]]
[1] "blood pressure" "sugar level"    "bmi"            "weight"        
[5] "skin thickness"

[[2]]
[1] "blood pressure" "sugar level"    "bmi"            "weight"        
[5] "weight"
```

You could then do something like:

```r
lapply(r, function(v) lm(reformulate(v, response = "your_response"), data = your_data)
```

Note that if you're doing linear regression, `leaps::regsubsets()` will do this sort of thing much more efficiently ... and in general penalized regression (ridge, lasso, or elastic-net e.g. via the `glmnet()` package) will produce better predictive accuracy, more efficiently, then fitting separate models to loads of parameter combinations ...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not entirely clear.  It seems that you want to run regressions for all 9 variables taken 5, 6, 7, 8. 9 at a time?  If so, that would be 256 regressions.  However, since the independent variables are assumed to be mutually independent you can simply run a regression using all 9 independent variables and then run a test to rank order variable importance.  Then take the top 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 highest ranked independent variables and test for RMSE or other statistic.

Here is a tutorial that shows you how to do it using the tidymodels platform if you are interested: https://gmubusinessanalytics.netlify.app/lesson-05-r-tutorial.html

Comment: where were the predictor/independent variables assumed to be mutually independent??? I didn't see the OP state that anywhere, and it's not a typical assumption outside of data from designed experiments ...

Answer (score 0):

```
install.packages("gtools")
library(gtools)
combined5<-combinations(n = 10, r = 5, v = combinations, repeats.allowed = FALSE)
```